# 4-20 mA output from Arduino for VFD

Tags: speed, vfd, 4-20ma

I'm a beginner with electronics, so everything has to be explained in simple terms to me.

I have an Arduino with a program which provides a value via the Analog output, so that is anything from 0-5 V.

On the other side, I have a VFD with an IO card which allows it to connect to a 4-20 mA current loop, to vary the speed of the motor accordingly.

How do I convert from, let's say, 0-5 V output (PWM) from Arduino, to the 4-20 mA in a somewhat cheap and safe way (I don't want to destroy the VFD [and possibly the Arduino])?

Currently, I am using the circuit below:

The problem is that the simulation on "Multisim" is giving accurate results. However practically, the circuit did not give the accurate results.

For example:

- When V = 5 V output (from Arduino analog), I = 20 mA (V=IR) --> which is correct
- But, when V = 3.3 V output (from Arduino analog), I = 16 mA (V=IR)--> which is incorrect, as it should be 13 mA

Will this circuit work practically

Comment: If V = 3.3 volts then Iout should be 14.56 mA. I don't know how you got 13 mA. OK you assumed that 1 volts = 4 mA rather than 0 volts is 4 mA. You need to decide this.

Comment: How it is 14.56mA? Plz Explain

Comment: 0 volts maps to 4 mA and 5 volts maps to 20 mA plus a straight-line graph.

Comment: Oh! I got it.Thanks

Comment: FOR 1-5V to 0-20mA:

I am very confused! When I use 3.3V ouput from Arduino Nano Power Pin--> Iout=13mA (which is ok).

But,When I use 3.3V ouput from Arduino Nano Analog pin(PWM)--> Iout=16mA (I can't understand this value).

At 2.5V output from Arduino Nano Analog Pin--> Iout=13.7mA.

Is seems their is a problem using Analog pins of arduino nano.??

Comment: @usmanshah - As I commented below as well, where you have asked the same thing: Please stop asking about the 16 mA value in *this* question. You have now asked that in a separate question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/501845/4-20ma-output-from-arduino-nano). Therefore you **must stop** asking it here, otherwise you will waste people's time by duplicating the question in multiple places. I recommend that you delete your comment above which asks that question, to avoid people wasting time here, since you have already asked that separate question. Thanks.

Comment: @usmanshah - Hi, Why have you edited the question to remove the schematic? Without that, the question makes no sense (since you are asking about that schematic!). Therefore unless there is some specific reason that hasn't been explained, you can expect someone to undo your latest edit soon, as it appears to be either (a) a mistake or (b) a prohibited vandalism of the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only work practically if the supply ground is isolated and an op-amp is used that is "single supply" such as an LM358. You could use the LM741 if you added a negative supply, such as -5V but that would be a lot of trouble to use an obsolete part. Using a more negative supply than -6V or so would expose Q2 to damage if the inverse Vbe rating is not high enough.

So you feed 5V from the PWM for 20mA (100% PWM) and 20% PWM (1V) for 4mA.

Maximum load resistance is about (12V-5.2V)/0.02A = 340 ohms to allow a full 20mA out.

Comment: Obviously you need to low-pass filter the PWM to be sure it will work properly.

Comment: what value of C and R should be used?

Comment: That sounds like a different (new) question and it will depend on your PWM frequency and allowable ripple.

Comment: 0


FOR 1-5V to 0-20mA:

I am very confused! When I use 3.3V ouput from Arduino Nano Power Pin--> Iout=13mA (which is ok).
Similarly, with 3.3V Battery -> Iout=13mA (which is ok).

But,When I use 3.3V ouput from Arduino Nano Analog pin(PWM)--> Iout=16mA (I can't understand this value).

At 2.5V output from Arduino Nano Analog Pin--> Iout=13.7mA.

Is seems their is a problem using Analog pins of arduino nano.??

Comment: 3.3V = 13.2mA with 250 ohms.

Comment: @usmanshah - Please stop asking about the 16 mA value in *this* question. You have now asked that in a separate question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/501845/4-20ma-output-from-arduino-nano). Therefore you **must stop** asking it here, otherwise you will waste people's time by duplicating the question in multiple places. I recommend that you delete your comments above which ask that question, to avoid people wasting time here, since you have already asked that separate question. Thanks.